# How to connect Firebase again to the mobile UI?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm unable to connect to Firebase because I'm getting a error.

I have tried to delete iOS app from the Firebase console and redo the steps, but that didn't work. I deleted some code that might have some effect on Firebase, and that did not work.

Error:

```
Zuhairs-MacBook-Pro:open311_s zuhairhallak$ flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team
in Xcode project: M6E2BGCTT7
Running pod install...                                              6.9s
Running Xcode build...                                                  

 ├─Assembling Flutter resources...                           2.8s
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         5.3s
Xcode build done.                                           12.5s
5.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.50800000 started 
5.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
Installing and launching...                                        15.2s
Error connecting to the service protocol: HttpException: , uri = http://127.0.0.1:1042/ws
```

I'm supposed to be able connect to Firebase without getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

The error shown at the bottom of your log has nothing to do with firebase.
`15.2s Error connecting to the service protocol: HttpException: , uri = http://127.0.0.1:1042/ws`
Is most likely a debugger connection problem between your Mac and your iPhone. There are a couple of issues on GitHub already addressing this problem.

You may find further instructions on how to solve that problem here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25112

Your firebase problem seem to be somewhere else. Could you paste the relevant code?

Comment: I just found out that this problem only exists with iPhone being connected to the mac. When I run the app on the Simulator everything is okay.

Comment: If you urn off Wifi on you Phone you should be able to run the App without problems.  Also could you take a look at your XCode BundleIdentifier? Does it contain a dash `-`? If so you may want to replace that with an underscore `_`. Then you should be able to run your App even with Wifi enabled.

Answer (score 0):

[this is an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13747) submitted about the same problem.
I recommend you watch the ticket if the solutions below didn't work for you.

**Possible solutions for you:**

Disabling sync with iPhone.
[image]

recover on the firebase file for IOS app: GoogleService-Info.plist
then open Xcode and drag the file to the application directory.
Warning: you have to go through Xcode otherwise it will not work.
[image]